# How do I store a DataTable in profile

Tags: asp.net, profile, provider, user-profile, personalization

How do I store a DataTable in profile (**Personalzition provider**,custom type)

Answer (score 0):

DataTables have `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` functions.

So you could store and retrieve the XML string.